# Communication between two kernel kprobes/kretprobes

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, kprobe

Is it possible to capture a kernel function's return value using a kretprobe and communicate it to another kretprobe which is hooked on to another kernel function.

Comment: If handlers for both probes are declared in the same module, they can communicate as usual (via module's variables).

Comment: @Tsyvarev so basically you are saying that I should write the code for both the return probes within a single module and communicate between their handlers via global variables ?

Comment: Yes, this is a good way.

Comment: Alright and since I am new to kernel programming I would like to know how to capture the return value of function on which we are planting the return probe. What I am trying to do is make two return probes, one hooked on to load_elf_binary() function in fs/binfmt_elf.c file and the other hooked on to randomize_stack_top() function which is called within the load_elf_binary function. Now I want to use the value returned by the randomize_stack_top() in the first probe.

Comment: Just store return value of ` randomize_stack_top` in its kretprobe handler to some module's global variable, then read this variable in kretprobe handler for `load_elf_binary`.

Answer (score 0):

One example of how to do this using eBPF & bcc:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bcc import BPF

BPF(text="""
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
BPF_HASH(rvalues, u64, unsigned long);
int kretprobe__randomize_stack_top(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    u64 zero = 0;
    unsigned long rvalue = PT_REGS_RC(ctx);
    rvalues.lookup(&zero);
    return 0;
}

int kretprobe__load_elf_binary(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    u64 zero = 0;
    unsigned long *rvalue_ptr = rvalues.lookup(&zero);
    if (rvalue_ptr) {
        unsigned long rvalue = *rvalue_ptr;
        bpf_trace_printk("value returned by randomize_stack_top: %d", rvalue);
    }
    return 0;
}
""").trace_print()
```

The value returned by `randomize_stack_top` is saved in the hash map `rvalues` with the key 0 (it's also possible to use a BPF_ARRAY since the key is fixed here). The value is retrieved in `load_elf_binary` with a simple lookup on the hash map.

Note: If you have several processes calling these functions, you can use their PID as keys for the hash map to discriminate between different returned values.

---

bcc offers an higher-level, Python API to load eBPF programs in the kernel and interact with them. eBPF programs can be used instead of kernel modules to instrument kprobes. For more information on bcc, see [the tutorial on the repository](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/tutorial_bcc_python_developer.md).